# Cannot install lintroller

Tags: npm

Here is a command I am running and it's output with the error message:

```
$ npm install lintroller
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lintroller
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lintroller
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/esprima
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jshint
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jslint
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/w3cjs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-node
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jshint
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jslint
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/esprima
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/w3cjs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-node
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/superagent
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/shelljs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cli
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/console-browserify
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-reporters
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-growl-reporter
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/requirejs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/walkdir
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/gaze
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/shelljs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nopt
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cli
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/superagent
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/0.6.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable/1.0.14
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/1.2.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/emitter-component/1.0.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/methods/0.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookiejar/1.3.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/reduce
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/console-browserify
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-reporters
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-growl-reporter
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/requirejs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/walkdir
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/gaze
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/0.6.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable/1.0.14
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/1.2.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/growl
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/emitter-component/1.0.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fileset
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/methods/0.0.1
npm WARN package.json methods@0.0.1 No README.md file found!
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookiejar/1.3.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/reduce
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/Users/richard.knop/src/statements-dashboard/node_modules/lintroller/node_modules/jasmine-node/node_modules/jasmine-reporters'
npm ERR! error rolling back  lintroller@2.3.3 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/Users/richard.knop/src/statements-dashboard/node_modules/lintroller/node_modules/jasmine-node/node_modules/jasmine-reporters']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 53,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/Users/richard.knop/src/statements-dashboard/node_modules/lintroller/node_modules/jasmine-node/node_modules/jasmine-reporters' }
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: reduce@'RedVentures/reduce#346d59'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.1.0","0.1.2"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/opt/boxen/nvm/v0.8.8/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:553:10)
npm ERR!     at /opt/boxen/nvm/v0.8.8/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:477:15
npm ERR!     at saved (/opt/boxen/nvm/v0.8.8/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:138:7)
npm ERR!     at /opt/boxen/nvm/v0.8.8/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:220:7
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.3.0
npm ERR! command "/opt/boxen/nvm/v0.8.8/bin/node" "/opt/boxen/nvm/v0.8.8/bin/npm" "install" "lintroller"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/richard.knop/src/statements-dashboard
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.8
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.59
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/growl
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fileset
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/glob
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/richard.knop/src/statements-dashboard/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

And error message:

```
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/Users/richard.knop/src/statements-dashboard/node_modules/lintroller/node_modules/jasmine-node/node_modules/jasmine-reporters'
npm ERR! error rolling back  lintroller@2.3.3 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/Users/richard.knop/src/statements-dashboard/node_modules/lintroller/node_modules/jasmine-node/node_modules/jasmine-reporters']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 53,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/Users/richard.knop/src/statements-dashboard/node_modules/lintroller/node_modules/jasmine-node/node_modules/jasmine-reporters' }
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: reduce@'RedVentures/reduce#346d59'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.1.0","0.1.2"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/opt/boxen/nvm/v0.8.8/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:553:10)
npm ERR!     at /opt/boxen/nvm/v0.8.8/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:477:15
npm ERR!     at saved (/opt/boxen/nvm/v0.8.8/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:138:7)
npm ERR!     at /opt/boxen/nvm/v0.8.8/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:220:7
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.3.0
npm ERR! command "/opt/boxen/nvm/v0.8.8/bin/node" "/opt/boxen/nvm/v0.8.8/bin/npm" "install" "lintroller"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/richard.knop/src/statements-dashboard
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.8
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.59
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think this is a superagent bug, try making sure superagent version is >= 0.15.5. https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/issues/221

Comment: For what it's worth, I just pushed LintRoller v2.3.5 to NPM. Did you ever solve this issue?